# Java subclass method override father method

Tags: java

Lets assume that i have something like that

```
public class Child1 extends Father{
    public void run(){
        mymethod();
    }
}
```

```
public class Child2 extends Father{       
    @Override
    protected boolean mymethod(){
        if(...){
            return true;
        }
        super.mymethod() //calls the method on father class if reach to this statement
    }
}
```

```
public class Father{
    protected boolean my method(){
    }
}
```

Here is my code structure. Lets pretend that i reach the statement mymethod() on the class Child1, and then i want to advance to the mymethod on the class child2 instead of the father method. And one thing important: i can't change the mymethod() on Father class. So, it is possible to do this flow:

```
Child1 -> Child 2 -> return true
or
Child1 -> Child 2 -> (goto if "if statement" fail) Father
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean `else { return super.mymethod(); }`? Although I fail to understand how you would plan to go from Child1 to any method in Child2 at all, as those 2 classes have no relationship with each other except a common parent.

Comment: I think that would only be possible if you had an instance of Child2 inside of Child1.  Since you can't extend two classes, this is a tough problem to solve.  Is it possible just to combine child1 and child2 classes?

Comment: As `Child1` and `Child2` do not share direct parenthood, you can't use virtual method invocation to invoke the implementation of `myMethod` from a `Child2` instance from `Child1`'s `run`, without explicitly invoking it on a `Child2` instance.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? You have abstracted away so much that it becomes impossible to suggest a solution that might work for your actual task at hand. Right now the best advice I can give is: Have you tried composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: Suggested readings : inheritance in Java and object creation in heap. new Child1() is an object of Child1, it inherits instance states and method from its super class **but it  Does not know anything about Child2** Any implementation specific to child2 is not present in an object of child1